# Retrieving data from SharePoint Site

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, datasource

This may not sound like a coherient question, but I need to find some way to connect to a hosted SharePoint website and pull data from it to a C# application. I suppose it could be from any database or list program, but since we already have our data stored on our SharePoint 2007 site, it would probably just be easiest to incorporate it somehow.

My question is this: where is the best resource regarding how to get started with this? I've started going through [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094%28office.14%29.aspx) to try to get some understanding, but it's still somewhat foreign to me. (I've never used SharePoint before (obviously), so I'm still trying to acquire some knowledge about how it interacts with standalone .NET applications.)

Essentially, I'll have a standalone application deployed on an environment that doesn't host the SharePoint server, which means (I think) I need to call the Windows Sharepoint Services. However, that's the extent of my "knowledge". Any more guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try asking this question at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the SharePoint web services for accessing data from SP.  For instance, to access a list, you would use the SharePoint List Web Service.  Take a look at this reference for a list of available services:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862916(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this site before and it looked like a direction I should be heading in. However, do you know if these Web Services only support 32-bit versions of Windows? I only have 64-bit machines and, from what I've tried, I can't install them on here. (Sorry for adding another question...)

Comment: I don't see any reason that the services wouldn't work on 64-bit.